# Getting Value from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am developing ios app and working on google map. draw lines on google map and coordinates add on mutableArray and those coordinate save on NSUSERDEFAULT data save perfectly.but when getting the data on nsuserdefault and show coordinate on google maps.but in GMSMutablePath app crash error msg is exc_bad_access (code=1,address=0*4).please help thanks in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [coordinateArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [coordinateArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *lat = [dic valueForKey:@"lat"];
        NSString *longitude = [dic valueForKey:@"long"];
        _valuePoints.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
        _valuePoints.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
        GMSMutablePath *path = [[GMSMutablePath alloc]              initWithPath:self.polyline.path];
        [path addCoordinate:_valuePoints];
        self.polyline.path = path;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the part where you save the data to NSUserDefaults, also please explain what is the expected behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: [_arr addObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:&coordinate length:sizeof(coordinate)] ];
    NSLog(@"%@",_arr);
    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_arr] forKey:@"numberArray"];
    [defaults synchronize];

Comment: save coordinates

Comment: @DeepakKumar, why you shouldn't edit your question instead of posting comment.

Comment: my advice you prefer plist or any json file to save coordinate .

Comment: @DeepakKumar, once you convert the coordinate to NSData, you can directly store the value in NSUserDefauls like this.

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&coordinate length:sizeof(coordinate)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"coordinate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 0):

Save the coordinate to the array directly,

```
[_arr addObject:coordinate]; 
NSLog(@"%@",_arr);
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Instead of saving the value as a string, save the array itself

```
[defaults setObject:_arr forKey:@"numberArray"]; 
[defaults synchronize];
```

When reading data back from NSUserDefaults,

```
NSArray *coordinateArray = [ud objectForKey:@"numberArray"];
```

From coordinateArray you can loop through the objects to get the CLLocation objects using the latitude and longitude of the saved coordinate.